# mean curvature flow vs. ricci flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

Both of these seem to describe very similar flows: curve-shortening flows of a high-dimensional hypersurface,  which may form singularities, where the flow velocity at any point is normal to the surface and depends on the curvature there.

I guess it comes down to the difference between Ricci curvature and mean curvature. What are these differences? How does it affect the resulting flow? In what situations would we use Ricci vs. MCF?

Bonus question is, how do these compare to other similar flows?

Comment: Not a detailed answer, but one major difference is that Ricci curvature is intrinsic and mean curvature is extrinsic (so MCF also depends on the ambient metric). <> Fixed points of one flow may "evolve rapidly" with respect to the other. For example, a slice $M \times \{p\} \subset M \times N$ of a Riemannian product has vanishing second fundamental form but arbitrary Ricci curvature; an Einstein manifold in a suitable warped product has constant Ricci but "arbitrary second fundamental form."

Comment: I find this way too broad (I counted about 4 questions here, with the last one very much open-ended). It is also unclear what your knowledge of these flows is. To begin with: Do you know what these flows are? Did you try to read any papers on the subject or at least the relevant Wikipedia articles? There are potentially interesting questions here, but, if you have a reasonably  technical knowledge of both flows, the better place to ask is Mathoverflow.